# Running React-Native Android App on Ubuntu using Genymotion Emulator

Tags: react-native, genymotion

I am building an app using react-native and i was using android default emulator without any problems. The only issue i am having is the emulator is really slow.

I wanted to try genymotion and installed it. How ever when i run react-native run-android it cannot find the Genymotion Emulator. Here is the Error i am seeing in the console.

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 8.329 secs

This build could be faster, please consider using the Gradle Daemon: http://gradle.org/docs/2.4/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
error: 
Starting the app (/home/hduser/Android/Sdk//platform-tools/adb shell am start -n com.legacitinative/.MainActivity...
error: no devices/emulators found
```

I am not sure why it cannot find the emulator.

Appreciate any help.

Thanks
Sateesh

Comment: Tried my suggestion?

Comment: Yes i tried it and when i run adb devices it is showing the emulator i created using the Genymotion. How ever when i try to run react-native run-android it still failing with the same Error "no devices/emulators" found.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue, I just downloaded genymotion, installed it, added a new generic device, ran react-native run-android and it worked, nothing else. Maybe try upgrading react native and the react-native cli.

Answer (score 0):

`$ cd /home/hduser/Android/Sdk/platform-tools`

`$ ./adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`

Try if adb can see your device with

`$ ./adb devices`